# Troubleshooting event handler for group radio buttons in Ext JS

Tags: php, extjs, phpmyadmin

I'm adding a radio group to a toolbar in Ext JS, but my on check event is not working with it. What should I do to identify the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking why an event handler isn't firing on an [`Ext.form.RadioGroup`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.RadioGroup), you need to make sure you're listening on the right event, and make sure that the handler is registered properly. All the events that the RadioGroup has are listed in the link above.

Assuming, for example, that you want to check that the 'change' event is being fired correctly, try the following code:

```
yourRadioGroup.addListener("change", function() {
    alert("Help!")
})
```

In the absence of information, this is all the help I can provide.